# Make an animated chain along a curve without simulation nodes using Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I want a chain to be animated along a curve but I don't want to use the simulation nodes branch for work because can't trust on it's reliability.
Right now I have a chain, got the chain links moving along the curve too but for some reason I can't figure out how to correct their rotation once they get moving.
It is not the same as the other chain question which this is being flagged as being a duplicate of, that one only solves the question if the chain isn't being animated. Without simulation nodes you need to evaluate the rotation of each instance, and that's what I'm asking how to do. Let me ask the question.
[image]
[image]
Here's what it looks like at frame one

[image]
How it looks after a couple of frames

Comment: What are you using to deform the chain along the curve? Can you share the file on blend-exchange? Thanks

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=SL1xln0j" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/SL1xln0j/)
Here's the file, the node setup isn't at all pretty pardon me for that, appreciate the help.

Comment: Even though there is no animation involved in the [question that is currently marked as a duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278223/), it is still the same problem: it is about correct spacing and rotation of the individual chain links. The animation is secondary in this case, because it has not much to do with the underlying problem. Therefore, the solution we are looking for is the solution to both questions.

Comment: @Kuboå I still think this is a duplicate question, so I'm very curious to see your answer! ;-)

Comment: @quellenform I guess this is about my vote to reopen this question? When I cast my vote this q did not yet have a file attached, and looking at the provided pictures it wasn't obvious to me they were duplicates of each other, since: 1/ the other one is about the minutiae of *perfect* alignment in case of sharp corners, while this one looks to be on a lower level of keeping what simple alignment it already has 2/ no mention of animation on the other 3/ no accepted answer on the other anyways... yet, this was quickly closed without much communication with OP and time to understand it completely.

Comment: So I thought it was hasty to close this question. Doesn't mean I'm going to answer it myself, or even that I *can* answer it, really. I apologize if you think that was an overstepping of boundaries or inconsideration of moderation rules? Now that we have a file, if it turns out to be basically the same q, it can be closed again obviously, but I do think OP should've been given this much courtesy first.

Comment: @Kuboå Everything is fine, you have not made a mistake! And sorry everyone, possibly I had actually reacted too quickly here. However, since I had already dealt with the topic, it was clear to me relatively quickly that it is the same problem, even if the question is formulated differently, or is partly aimed at other aspects. I leave the question open for the time being, but I am afraid that here not so fast a suitable answer can be found, which would differ from an answer with the other question.