# Geometry node paved path

Tags: geometry-nodes

I need to make a paved path. For that I need to offset a bezier curve multiple time and for each curve I want to instance paving stone on it but the shortest curve need to have less paving stone on it and longest curve need to have more paving stone on it.

[image]

[image]

---

[image]

So I manage to repeat the operation but then I want to get more point on exterior curves

[image]

also reuse your setup but only work on one curve

---

Thank you so much for the help it works exactly like I wanted. I just want the high part to not rotate when I lower the other tangent.
And do you know how I could offset the paving stone every 2 so its not perfectly aligned ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once you offset your curves (using their normals for example), resample them by length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified setup to fill a path with bricks, you could improve it in multiple ways, for example by resampling the curves by length (just one node), or deal with possible pinching (much more than one node)...

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes perfect this works perfectly and much more optimized and simpler node setup

Comment: how could I keep the upper part horizontally aligned when I low the end point of the curve   https://imgur.com/a/n5LmNHg

Comment: @croustib4t set z-up twist method, or multiply the normal by <1, 1, 0> and normalize.

Comment: ok I set a z-up twist method and now works perfectly fine

Answer (score 3):

Nearly the same as [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/278223/perfect-chain-generator). And still a not perfect answer, but that could do the job (?)...

[image]

Get the pavement tile size in its X axis, add a delta because of the rounded part (if not they will overlap).

Resample the curve with this previous size, but equidistant (see below).

Make a curve from the result, subdivide it as the tiles will go on these subdivisions.

Get points from the curve in order to have its tangent.

Instantiate the tiles for each odd index (the subdivisions above) and rotate their X axis along the curve tangent.

"Resample equidistant": uses a dichotomie along the curve factor so that all points are on the curve but equidistant (native resampling does not guaranty this distance). Please see the question mentioned above for more details.

Blender V4.0 (needs repeat zone)

[image]

Edit:

I've add a loop around the solution above, so that you can do it with one single curve.

[image]

This loop resamples and shift the initial curve along its normal, so that we have the successive curves forming the path width.

[image]

Comment: yes that what I wanna do but there you duplicated the curve but I want to do it procedural, I just want one principal curve for the control

Comment: you should describe how the curve guides will be. How to define the path width, for instance.

Comment: How can I do if I doest want the high part to rotate when I lower the other tangent. And do you know how I could offset the paving stone every 2 so its not perfectly aligned ?

Comment: for a irregular tiling, try this: calculate the tile to curve length ratio, and use it to cap the curve alternatively. For the end part, use a boolean to cut exedent tile parts.